# How to change formatting on specific cells in RadGridView

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, telerik, radgridview

So I have a dynamic RadGridView. This means that I add Columns programmatically to the control. basically like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    Binding b = new Binding(string.Format("Collection[{0}].ValueIWant", i));
    binding.StringFormat = "{0:0.##}";
    GridViewDataColumn column = new GridViewDataColumn()
    {
        Header = HeaderFor(i),
        DataMemberBinding = b,
        DataType = typeof(double?)
    };

    Control.columns.Add(column);
}
```

Now I need to add new lines that show the percentage between line `1 and 2`, `2 and 3` and so on.

I've managed to do that but I'm not sure how I would manage to change the String.format specifically for those cells instead of the whole column.

CellTemplateSelector came to mind but I'm not sure that is a good idea as this might mean I have to set the binding again, not knowing the value of `i` and such. Also I only want to change the string.format on the binding.

As I'm manipulating the number as a double (0,5 is 50%, 50 is 5000%) I guess I have to mask the input as well. not sure if String.Format does that for me as well or if I should use `RadMaskedInput`

Comment: Do you want to set the format of cell which is in edit mode?

Comment: Just in display mode would be enough to get the bounty but I would also try to do a MaskedInput in the edit.

Comment: What is the `DataSource` for the GridView (or if there's no data source, how do you populate the rows)?

Comment: Sometimes I can't see the trees because of the forest. It was brought to my attention that Telerik has a RowStyleSelector so I could easily style the rows I wanted. I was making this way more complicated than it needed to be.

Answer (score 2):

Use an `IValueConverter` to convert the column's value at each row to its appropriate representation.  So for the binding on a computed column, use:

```
// bind to the row data itself, not any specific property
Binding b = new Binding();
b.Converter = new RowToFormattedValueConverter
```

This will send the complete row data to the converter; so you should be able to either use some existing property of the row to figure out which type it is (regular or percentage), or add an extra hidden property/column to specify it explicitly.  The converter would then look something like this:

```
public class RowToFormattedValueConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var rowData = (MyModelType)value;
        string formattedResult;
        if (rowData.IsPerecentageRow) 
        {
            formattedResult= string.Format("{0:P1}", rowData.ValueIWant);
        }
        else
        {
            formattedResult= string.Format("{0:0.##}", rowData.ValueIWant);
        }
        return formattedResult;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```